# How do I add custom annotation for use within SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

We would like to use a row level security policy with EF Core. We are trying to get it so we can mark an entity with a custom annotation like `.HasAnnotation("IsMultiTenant", true)` and then add the below SQL to the create table statements so we can avoid having to manually remember to add the sql code to each table as it's made.

```sql
ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicate(TenantID) ON dboExampleTable,
ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicate(TenantID) ON dbo.ExampleTable
```

We have added the predicate to the model via the fluent API in the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` for the entity.

```cs
builder.HasAnnotation("IsMultiTenant", true);
```

We have created a custom `SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator` as below

```cs
public class MySqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    public MySqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator(
        MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
        ICommandBatchPreparer commandBatchPreparer)
        : base(dependencies, commandBatchPreparer)
    { }

    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IModel? model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, bool terminate = true)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(operation);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);

        base.Generate(operation, model, builder, terminate);

        if ((operation["IsMultiTenant"] as bool?) == true)
        {
            builder.AppendLine("ALTER SECURITY POLICY rls.tenantAccessPolicy");

            using (builder.Indent())
            {
                builder
                    .AppendLine($"ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicate(TenantID) ON {Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name, operation.Schema)},")
                    .Append($"ADD BLOCK PREDICATE rls.fn_tenantAccessPredicate(TenantID) ON {Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name, operation.Schema)}")
                    .AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator);
            }

            EndStatement(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

But cannot work out how to get the annotation to be available within this method. The table doesn't appear to have it available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

- We have added `.ReplaceService<>` to our context for the above
- The annotation does show inside the model snapshot file
- Did notice this #22946 but the API @ajcvickers suggested doesn't exist anymore
- Have read a lot of issues but couldn't work out an answer

Comment: Why you are looking into `operation["IsMultiTenant"]`? You should use `model.FindEntityType(...).FindAnnotation("IsMultiTenant")`. Searching should be performed by table name.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I couldn't find any docs on any of the APIs so I was just trying to get it to work. So the table name goes into `FindEntityType(TableName)`?

Comment: Updating that to `model.FindEntityType(operation.Name).FindAnnotation("IsMultiTenant")` didn't work either :( nor does typing the table name in manually in a string.

Comment: no, TableName is not class name. I just pointed you in right direction. Annotations are stored in `Model`. Enumerate and find appropriate Entity.

Comment: ah, fair enough. Do you know where I can get the entities class name from from within the Generate method?

Comment: You can't, it contains only Table Name.

Comment: [GetTableName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.gettablename?view=efcore-7.0) + `model.GetEntityTypes().FirstOrDefault(et => operation.Name == et.GetTableName())` - something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the help that has worked :)